# Button/link to redirect up or down a level

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two different levels within my site, but each have a similar structure. For example:

http://example.com/demo/insights.html

and

http://example.com/demo/complete/insights.html

What I'd like to do is add a link/button that the user can click to go up or down a level depending on where they are. The last part of the URL (e.g., insights.html) would stay the same. It's just whether or not the directory would change up or down.

So, if I'm on http://example.com/demo/insights.html, there would be a button to get to http://example.com/demo/complete/insights.html. If I was on http://example.com/demo/complete/insights.html
then there'd be a button to get to http://example.com/demo/insights.html.

I have a lot of pages like this, but I'd like to avoid hand-coding links on every page. I'm looking for something using javascript/jquery that will evaluate the directory level and the last part of the URL and redirect accordingly.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.location.href
```

will give you the url of the page you are on, from there its just a matter of splitting `split()` the location and add/remove the required url substring

you can then add the new url into a common 'a' tag's href property on the page

As a rough example

```
var loc = window.location.href,
    someSplits = loc.split("http://example.com/demo/"),
    //you can do better reg ex, this is just quick
    page = someSplits[1]; // this will give you the remaining url

// OR just replace the part you dont want

var loc = window.location.href,
    page = loc.replace('http://example.com/demo/', ''); 
// this will give you the remaining url
```

Comment: The first script you gave just caused my page to continuously reload and never fully load. The someSplits line is throwing an error as undefined in not a function.

Comment: really, I have no issues, what browser are you using? Also they just split the location, nothing in there will cause a page to load or fail

Comment: No idea what I did wrong, but started from scratch and it's working now. Your answer gives me just what I need. I think I can take it from here. What's the difference between the two examples you have?

Comment: one divides the location path into parts, one just deletes some of it, in terms of outcome it doesnt really matter which you use. Glad you've got it working

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to count slashes:

```
var link = window.location.href;
var deep = link.match(/\//g).length - 3;
var chunks = link.split(/\//);
if (deep) { // level 2
    link = chunks[0] + '//' + chunks[2] + '/' + chunks[4]; // get rid of one level (chunks[3])
} else { // level 1
    link = chunks[0] + '//' + chunks[2] + '/extra-level/' + chunks[3]; // add a level
}
```

Comment: This would work in principle, but I need to generate the link to go up/down dynamically too otherwise I could just handcode the links into every page.

Comment: Please see edit: now you just have to give your button/link the new value

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
location.assign('../'+location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1))
```